# Error when installing apache 2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2, software-installation

When I install the apache2 in my Ubuntu there is an error like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2-bin
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and describe how you tried to install apache. Which commands have you used etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try with running an update before the installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will get the information about package distributions.